# git filter-branch --subdirectory-filter fails with "Bad file number - could not get commits"

Tags: git, git-bash, git-filter-branch

I'm trying to move a subdirectory in my git repo, to become a new repository (preserving the existing history).

Following various suggestions online for this, I've cloned the existing repo, removed the remote, and now want to use the git filter-branch command to strip everything from the new repo except the directory I want. But when I run the command, I get an error.

```
$ git filter-branch --subdirectory-filter myDirectory -- --all
C:\Program Files (x86)\Git/libexec/git-core\git-filter-branch: line 269: /libexe
c/git-core/git: Bad file number
Could not get the commits
```

I'm using git-bash on Windows.

Looking at the source for git-filter-branch, the problem seems to be when trying to run this command:

```
git rev-list --reverse --topo-order --default HEAD \
    --parents --simplify-merges $rev_args "$@" > ../revs ||
    die "Could not get the commits"
```

I can run this command myself without problems - depending on what I substitute for the $rev_args value. When I pass in single commits, everything is fine. But in the script, it comes from here:

```
rev_args=$(git rev-parse --revs-only "$@")
```

If I run that command, I get back a string with many thousand commit IDs.

So I suspect the problem is simply that the command the script is trying to run is just too long for the shell to handle, resulting in the cryptic error message I saw.

Does that analysis sound correct? If so, what should I do about it?

I've found one workaround which I'll post below, but it seems pretty hacky and I'm hoping someone knows of a better way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found git-filter-branch on my PC (this was at /libexec/git-core/git-filter-branch for me, using git-bash on Windows)

Comment out lines 287-9 (`git rev-list .... || die "Could not get commits"`)

Replace with this:

```
rm ../revs
for rev in $rev_args
do
  git rev-list --reverse --topo-order --default HEAD \
    --parents --simplify-merges $rev "$@" >> ../revs
done
```

Then I could re-run my `git filter-branch --subdirectory-filter myDirectory -- --all` command again and all was well.

So, this seems a pretty horrible hack.

- Is there a better way?
- If not, can you suggest any improvements to this method?

Thanks!